# Comment filter by logged user

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, many-to-many

Good afternoon,

I have three models linked to eachother, Perfil, Puesto and Tags. Perfil model inherit from Abstractuser. To this model it has been added an additional information 'puesto de trabajo (job)' which is created in anothe model shown below.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from apps.Tags.models import Tags

class Puesto(models.Model):
    nombre_puesto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    etiquetas = models.ManyToManyField(Tags, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre_puesto)

class Perfil(AbstractUser):

    nom_puesto = models.ForeignKey(Puesto, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.username)
```

Tags model is created in another application, look:

models.py

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre)
```

Besides I have created another aplication to create comments which have the option to add tags.

The goal is to show the comments whose tags fits with the user profile tag. In order to reach that:

views.py

```
class ComentarioListar (LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url='/'
    redirect_field_name='redirigido'
    model = Comentario
    template_name = 'home/comentario_listar.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        aa=Puesto.objects.filter(nombre_puesto=self.request.user.nom_puesto)

        return Comentario.objects.exclude(autor__id=self.request.user.id)
        b=Perfil.objects.filter(nom_puesto=self.request.user)
        c=Puesto.objects.filter(nombre_puesto=b)
        return Comentario.objects.filter(tag__id=c)
```

This does not work, it's crazy! does anybody know how to show only the comments which fits with the user's tags??

Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find the answer. If you could help me I would be grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A given user's tags can be found at `Perfil.nom_puesto.etiquetas.all()`.

To find only `Comentario` objects that have tags in common with a given user, assuming `Comentario` has a many-to-many relationship to `Tags` called `tags`:

```
>> user_tags = request.user.nom_puesto.etiquetas.all()
>> matching_comments = Comentario.objects.filter(tags__in = user_tags).distinct()
```

Passing a list of objects to `__in` converts them to primary keys under the hood; Django then creates a queryset with a `Comentario` object for every match. If a user and comment had multiple tags in common then you'd see duplicate results, hence the use of `distinct()`.